# How to get unique string in a file using tcl

Tags: tcl

New in tcl programming.
I have a file that contains same strings like:

```
Dog
Dog
Cat
Cat
Cat
Dog
```

I want to get the unique string like:

```
Dog
Cat
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

as an alternative to Peter's answer

```
set unique [lsort -unique $ss]
```

Comment: That's even better, as long as you have Tcl 8.3 or later. Which probably doesn't exclude very many Tcl users ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
set ss {Dog Dog Cat Cat Cat Dog}
foreach s $ss {set unique($s) 1}
array names unique
```

Documentation: [array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: And you can create the list with `set fh [open your.file r]; set ss [split [read -nonewline $fh] \n]; close $fh`